# jQuery finding the correct id

Tags: jquery, ajax, element, var

I have a HTML script like this:

```
    <form id="no1">
      <input id="title" type="text" />
<input type="submit" />
    </div>

    <form id="no2">
      <input id="title" type="text" />
<input type="submit" />
    </div>
```

I then have a validation script using jQuery. However I would like it to validate the form which has been submitted.

At the moment when I click sumit the jQuery validates the wrong input (because they both have the same id name).

I tried this code, but it didn't work (the "this" is the form element):

```
var title = $(this).("input#title").val();
```

Comment: Try giving them **different** id names... I have a hunch that is should work then...

Comment: You may get this to work, but that would just be luck, and you may not be lucky with IE9.  There's no telling what the browser will do with duplicate id's.  Anyway, don't you need a name= , instead of id= , in order to pick out that submitted value on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(this).find('input#title').val()
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML ids should be unique.  You should be using unique ids with the same name, if the posted element needs to have the same name for both forms.

```
<form id="no1"> 
  <input id="title1" name="title" type="text" />
```

```
<form id="no2"> 
  <input id="title2" name="title" type="text" />
```

Your code can then be modified as:

```
$(this).find("[name='title']").val();
```

Assuming that `this` refers to the form element being submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Each ID on the page must be unique:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqmultiIDs.htm

Comment: I knew that, but I suppose I should stick to W3 standards. I will change it so it is title-1, title-2.  Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$(this).find('input#title').val();
```

Comment: @downvoter Why the downvote?  My answer is actually identical to the selected answer AND mine was submitted before his?